# Need help interpreting the info on my Wireless card to eliminate the interruptions

Tags: wifi

Wireless has been cut after every few minutes. The interruption affects not only the internet connection but also the wireless connection to the printer. 
I used lspci to discover my wireless info, and after I went ahead and typed:

~$ lspci -vv -s 02:00.0

Here's the output I got:

[image: screenshot]

So... What's that part about Interruption routed to IRQ about? And why is access denied in the capabilities? And how can I solve the problem of getting my connection interrupted every few minutes?
Thanks for any help you can provide.

**UPDATE:** The output I copy and pasted from the terminal earlier wasn't very readable and some parts were missing, so now I pasted a screenshot of the output instead.

Answer (score 0):

Write this command to terminal:
sudo systemd-analyze blame

And you can see the init time of system units.